# Jenkins docker plugin not using the global maven settings defined in Jenkins

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

I am trying to run a maven build inside a docker container but it keeps skipping the global maven settings defined in Jenkins. It works fine when I am not running a container build but the moment I enable the container build it fails.
Here is the declarative Jenkinsfile:

```
stages {
    stage("Prepare build environment"){
        steps{
            /* create the m2 folder if it doesn't exist yet, to make sure it has the correct uid:gid
                otherwise it will be mounted as root
            */
            sh("mkdir -p $HOME/.m2/repository")
            
            
        }
    }
    
    stage('Build') {
        agent {
            dockerfile {
                filename 'buildcontainer.Dockerfile'
                additionalBuildArgs JENKINS_BUILD_ARGS
                args DOCKER_RUN_ARGS
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Building... ' + env.BRANCH_NAME + ' ' + env.BUILD_NUMBER + ' ' + env.JOB_NAME

                withMaven(
                    mavenSettingsConfig: '1f226b6c-5037-42d3-a481-adbe8ab4f4bb' // (3)
                ){
                
                   runMaven("pom.xml", "jib:build -Djib.httpTimeout=60000")
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the solution myself:

```
stages {
    stage("Prepare build environment"){
        steps{
            /* create the m2 folder if it doesn't exist yet, to make sure it has the correct uid:gid
                otherwise it will be mounted as root
            */
            sh("mkdir -p $HOME/.m2/repository")
            
            
        }
    }
    
    stage('Build') {
        agent {
            dockerfile {
                filename 'buildcontainer.Dockerfile'
                additionalBuildArgs JENKINS_BUILD_ARGS
                args DOCKER_RUN_ARGS
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Building... ' + env.BRANCH_NAME + ' ' + env.BUILD_NUMBER + ' ' + env.JOB_NAME

              configFileProvider(
                [configFile(fileId: '1f226b6e-5037-42d3-a481-fdbe9ab4f4bb', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                   runMaven("pom.xml", "jib:build -Djib.httpTimeout=60000")
                }

        }
    }
}
```